# Openlayers geometry how to calculate area from square degrees to square kilometres?

Tags: geometry, transform, openlayers, map-projections

I get the multypoligon from webservice and I try to calculate area for that poligon with the following code:

```
var poly = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon(poligon);
var area = geom.getArea();
```

But that returns me area in square degrees, our projection is EPSG:3243 I was try to use function

```
OpenLayers.Layer.SphericalMercator.forwardMercator
```

But that didn't help me alot, is there any other solution or some other hint?

Cheers!

Comment: There is a solution to use other function getGeodesicArea()      and than it will looks like this                                                                var area = (geom.getGeodesicArea()/1000000)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the GeodesicArea() function and feed you projection to prevent defaul WGS84:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.getGeodesicArea

```
getGeodesicArea: function( projection )
```

something like this:

```
var projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3243");
var poly = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon(poligon);
var area = poly.getGeodesicArea( projection );
```